# Mercurial clone files all hidden in OSX

Tags: macos, mercurial

I've been using Mercurial (hg) with a Bitbucket repository on my work PC (Windows 7) and I'm now setting it up on a mac. But I'm finding that all of the files from the repository are hidden.

I've tried SourceTree, TortoiseHG and installing a Mercurial package and then "hg clone repository address htdocslocation" in terminal. But the same thing happens every time:

The folder itself in Finder looks empty but it has the correct file size (in this case about 300mb). When I show hidden files I can find the repository files in .hg/store/data/

Because the files are in a hidden directory, I can't get to them from localhost in a web browser.

Any ideas what I can do to get the repository files unhidden and in the root folder I've specified rather than inside .hg/store/data/?

I'm on OSX 10.9 Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware all into the `.hg` directory is hidden because is Mercurial internals. May be your `hg clone` command is not updating the files to the working directory (just your root folder). Use `hg update` to extract all the files from the `.hg` repository.

You can see the repository content with `hg log`.

Comment: Thank you so much santiagopim, it was my lack of understanding of the hg commands. 

`hg update` worked great. I've clearly been using hg gui's for too long!

I also read through this article - [http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html][1] - which gave me a much better understanding.


  [1]: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html